# Failed Google App Engine deployment. No matching distribution found for pywin32==xxx

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have run `gcloud app deploy` for my Django application, but it fails with the following errors at the end of the build log:

```
Step #1 - "builder": Collecting pywin32==227 (from -r requirements.txt (line 63))
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
Step #1 - "builder":   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==227 (from -r requirements.txt (line 63)) (from versions: none)
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==227 (from -r requirements.txt (line 63))
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR    error: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_download_wheels took 13 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     build process for FTL image took 18 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     full build took 18 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR    `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
Step #1 - "builder":   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==227 (from -r requirements.txt (line 63)) (from versions: none)
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==227 (from -r requirements.txt (line 63))
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": error: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1
Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder":     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
Step #1 - "builder":     exec code in run_globals
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 57, in main
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/ftl_error.py", line 58, in UserErrorHandler
Step #1 - "builder": IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '""/output'
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37_app_builder:python37_20200223_3_7_6_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

For reference, my requirements.txt file is included below:

```
aioredis==1.3.1
asgiref==3.2.3
astroid==2.3.3
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.3.0
autobahn==20.1.3
Automat==0.8.0
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.13.2
channels==2.4.0
channels-redis==2.4.1
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.3
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.8
daphne==2.4.1
dash==1.8.0
dash-core-components==1.7.0
dash-html-components==1.0.2
dash-renderer==1.2.3
dash-table==4.6.0
Django==3.0.2
django-crispy-forms==1.9.0
django-extensions==2.2.8
django-plotly-dash==1.1.5
django-redis==4.11.0
djangorestframework==3.11.0
docker==4.1.0
dpd-components==0.1.0
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Compress==1.4.0
future==0.18.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
hiredis==1.0.1
hyperlink==19.0.0
idna==2.8
incremental==17.5.0
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
msgpack==0.6.2
numpy==1.18.1
pandas==1.0.1
Pillow==7.0.0
plotly==4.5.0
psycopg2==2.8.4
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.19
PyHamcrest==2.0.0
pylint==2.4.4
pylint-django==2.0.14
pylint-plugin-utils==0.6
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
pypiwin32==223
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
pywin32==227
redis==3.3.11
requests==2.22.0
retrying==1.3.3
scipy==1.4.1
service-identity==18.1.0
simplejson==3.17.0
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
Twisted==19.10.0
txaio==20.1.1
typed-ast==1.4.1
urllib3==1.25.8
websocket-client==0.57.0
Werkzeug==0.16.1
wincertstore==0.2
wrapt==1.11.2
xlrd==1.2.0
zope.interface==4.7.1
```

I have tried downgrading to pywin32 versions as far as 223 when greater support was provided for python 3.7 according to their changelog on GitHub, but each retry presented identical build log errors with the version substituted.

I'm not really sure what's wrong exactly. Why can't GCP find the appropriate distribution?

Also, possibly related question, why does the traceback before the final IOError list the runpy.py file in the python2.7 directory? I specified the runtime python as 3.7 in my app.yaml, and also have written everything with python3 in mind...

Any help is appreciated, and sorry if I'm missing something really obvious here. Been wracking my brains for the past couple hours here to no avail :(

Comment: How did you generate your `requirements.txt` file? It looks like it might be the output of `pip freeze`, which means that you probably don't need all these dependencies for your application. Is something in your application actually using `pywin32`?

Comment: According to your post, I think maybe you could add your `.yaml` file. It'd be helpful much.

Comment: @DustinIngram Is there a better way to generate a `requirements.txt` file for projects destined for cross-platform deployment or use that avoids this issue? I've only ever seen `pip freeze` piping used, and it doesn't seem like this command can be modified to only output packages used in the project directory.

Comment: Also, obviously new to contributing to Stack Overflow, I'm curious about the tag removal edit. Is it because the root issue is not specific to `pywin32`? I thought it would make sense to keep the tag still so that noobs like me are more likely to have this question suggested when looking for help on it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pywin32` package only publishes built distributions for the Windows platform (note all the `win*` filenames [here](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/#files)).

You won't be able to install it on App Engine because the underlying platform is Linux, not Windows.

Comment: Yeah, first thing that came to mind.  The perils of dev on 1 platform, deploy on another.  Mac to Linux is much more forgiving though.

Comment: This in combination with your post comment helped me solve it. I didn't understand what the package even did, although now it seems pretty obvious from the name lol. I ended up just removing all the packages with distributions only for Windows and it built and runs fine. Thanks for helping me understand this more.